# SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet suddenly stops working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

At first I had the error of my rows being out of bounds? Then I get this error with "TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet is not a function" after I tampered a bit.

I'm not sure why my script isn't working. I have one function to just autoresize all my rows and another function to resize my rows a specific amount (this one keeps saying my rows are out of bounds) Both of these functions use to work for my rows, so I'm not sure what changed.

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Scripts')
        .addItem('Hide columns', 'hideCols')
        .addItem('Show Columns', 'show')
        .addItem('Auto Resize Rows', 'autoResizeRows')
        .addItem('Resize Rows', 'resizeRows')
        .addToUi()
}

function hideCols() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var cells = sheet.createTextFinder("Pictures").matchEntireCell(true).findAll();

  cells.map(x => sheet.hideColumns(x.getColumn()));
}

function show() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var cells = sheet.createTextFinder("Pictures").matchEntireCell(true).findAll();

  cells.map(x => sheet.showColumns(x.getColumn()));
}

function autoResizeRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet();
  var dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  ss.autoResizeRows(2, lastRow);
}

function resizeRows() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cellss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var responseData = cellss.getDataRange().getValues();
  cellss.setRowHeights(2,responseData.length, 300);
}
```

Fixed:

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Scripts')
        .addItem('Hide columns', 'hideCols')
        .addItem('Show Columns', 'show')
        .addItem('Auto Resize Rows', 'autoResizeRows')
        .addItem('Resize Rows', 'resizeRows')
        .addToUi()
}

function hideCols() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var cells = sheet.createTextFinder("Pictures").matchEntireCell(true).findAll();

  cells.map(x => sheet.hideColumns(x.getColumn()));
}

function show() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var cells = sheet.createTextFinder("Pictures").matchEntireCell(true).findAll();

  cells.map(x => sheet.showColumns(x.getColumn()));
}

function autoResizeRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssname = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var lastRow = ssname.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  ssname.autoResizeRows(2, lastRow-2);
}
function resizeRows() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cellss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var responseData = cellss.getDataRange().getValues();
  cellss.setRowHeights(2,responseData.length-2, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've a typo in this function:-

```
function autoResizeRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet();
  var ssname = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var lastRow = ssname.getLastRow();
  ssname.autoResizeRows(1, lastRow);
}
```

It's `getActiveSpreadsheet` not `getActiveSpreadSheet` that's why your code is breaking, change that `S`  to `s`.

Reference:-

[getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)

Comment: That was the fix for that specifically but more errors came up for autoResizeRows not working. Can't believe I didnt notice that. I double checked all the function spellings now. autoResizeRows(startRow, numRows) numRows is "The number of rows to auto-resize." I think its counting the number from position number 2 which is why my rows are out of bounds. When I did lastRow - 2 , my errors fixed itself

Comment: Modified my script @ChrisEvans, please confirm.

Comment: I need the autoresizing to start from 2nd row. But I'm getting more errors now randomly. I think the google scripts is just bugging out at this point.

Comment: If you only want to resize range which has data, then they you can use `var lastRow = ssname.getDataRange().getLastRow();` instead of `var lastRow = ssname.getLastRow();`

Comment: Either method is fine, I'd rather do all rows. I tried shortening it like what you did but I'm just getting this : TypeError: ss.autoResizeRows is not a function

Comment: Alright I fixed it somehow, I just added your ` var ssname = ss.getActiveSheet()`  and it fixed everything?

Comment: Isn't that just a variable, why would naming it ss vs ssname affect it?

Comment: Edit: Nvm I get what you mean autoResizeRows is from the sheets class XD so you made another variable to call the sheet instead of spreadsheet. Sorry im slow lol

Comment: Check the code, `ss` is getting the active spreadsheet where else `ssname` is getting the active sheet from that spreadsheet, `autoResizeRows` is a method under  class `Sheet`  , you need to have sheet to use it, when you're using it with `ss` you're  not pointing to sheet where `auto resize` operation should be done. you can also use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` and that will also work the same, no need to create another variable. see this documentation :- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoresizerowsstartrow,-numrows

Comment: Yes that makes a lot more sense. I have another question about getLastRow(). When I add a new row onto the sheet. The function won't recognize the newest row as the last one so when I run the script to resize, it works for all of them except the last one. Is that suppose to happen?